# PHP - How to echo a value from mapped Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a mapped Array named: `$mapped`

Below is a result of `var_dump($mapped);`

```
array(32) {
  ["Age: "]=> string(137) "21 Years. "
  ["Ethnicity: "]=> string(122) "Caucasian "
  ["Location: "]=> string(152) "Paris, France "
}
```

**The problem is** I don't get any results with: `echo $mapped["Age: "];`

I have tried:

```
echo $mapped["Age: "];           // No results
echo $mapped["Age:"];            // No results
echo $mapped[" Age:  "];         // No results
echo $mapped['Age: '];           // No results
echo $mapped['Age:'];            // No results
var_dump($mapped["Age: "]);      // result: NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? I want `echo $mapped["Age: "];` to result:  `21 Years`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why the colons at all? Get rid of them, use just regular words as keys...

Comment: Perhaps this is some space funkiness. Maybe there is more than one space that is swallowed by the browser? Make sure you copy & paste from the browser's source code view. (But what Henrique says applies too)

Comment: `string(137) "21 Years. "` But there's significantly less than 137 characters. You probably are not seeing all of the spaces actually present, as @Pekka웃 says.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos @Pekka @Waleed: Thank you for your input. Why I have colons in array is cause I get this array with `file_get_contents` and surly I want to trim them. Now I found out why I cant echo and it was after looking at source code I found out that this Array have a LOT of HTML codes inside. How can I remove HTML codes from this Array? Should I use `strip_tags` how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cybrog, white spaces are creating problem for you. Try the code below to remove the white space and access any element without any extra effort.

```
$keys = str_replace( ' ', '', array_keys($mapped) );
$values = array_values($mapped);
$mapped = array_combine($keys, $values); 
var_dump($mapped);
```

try this one to remove html

```
$keys = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", array_keys($mapped)));
$values = array_map("trim", array_map("strip_tags", array_values($mapped)));
$mapped = array_combine($keys, $values); 
var_dump($mapped);
```

Comment: I guess you are right. It looks like a whitespace/space after colon signs. But now I copy pasted my source code to a NEW text document and the whitespace/space made **NEW LINES**. So it looks like `space` but is actually `\n` Please have a look at my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873071

Comment: Cybrog, I have modified my answer. You can try this it will remove all html tags from keys and values.

Comment: Thanks a Million!!! This works 100%! thats exactly what I needed and what I was asking for. Thanks again for helping me Ram