# How to remove or trim special characters (\n) from Array?

Tags: php

I have created a Array and are not able to echo values from it. Below I have copy pasted source code results from my browser. As you can see `"]=>` starts on new line. How can I solve this

using this function:

```
function remap_alternating(array $values) {
    $remapped = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values) - 1; $i += 2) {

$remapped[strip_tags(trim($values[$i], " "))] = strip_tags(trim($values[$i + 1], " "));
    }
    return $remapped;
}

$mapped = remap_alternating($matches[0]);   

$keys = str_replace( ':', '', array_keys($mapped) );
$values = array_values($mapped);
$mapped = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

**Result of** `var_dump($mapped);` (Copy Paste from Browser Source Code)

```
array(32) {
  ["Age
"]=>
  string(9) "21 Yrs. 
"
  ["Ethnicity
"]=>
  string(6) "Black
"
  ["Location
"]=>
  string(36) "Dubai, Dubayy, United Arab Emirates
"
```

My question is how I can get `echo $mapped[Age];`to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the characters to trim in the second argument of trim(): https://www.php.net/trim

You look to be specifying only " ", in the trim() function you're using.  Leave the second argument blank so it will trim the default characters which includes \n.

Comment: The trim function which is there already is to trim whitespace/space. If I remove or edit it then the results will have a lot more of spaces. So I guess I cant edit the existing trim function but I can add more trim? In that case how should I do that? I need to trim `\n` after Age

Comment: Just delete the " " in the trim function...  The space is deleted by default in trim().  Read the link I posted.

Comment: FINALLY I could make it WORK!!! :D I removed `, " "` from LINE 5 and everything is working as expected :D